# Android: How to initiate an AIDL unbind from a Service?

Tags: android

Is it possible for an Android Service to forcefully teardown the AIDL connections of existing clients? The only way I know to tear down such connections today is if the client has initiated it using Context.unbindService()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You can let the activity know you would like the binding to be disconnected (e.g., callback/listener, `createPendingResult()`). Or, you can switch away from the binding pattern to the command pattern using `startService()`, in which case the service can shut down when it wants to via `stopSelf()`.